# search for a file in python when I only know few words that are in file

Tags: python, file, search

Beginner at python. I'm trying to search for a file saved in folder. For eg. file name is "Tommee Profitt, Fleurie, Mellen Gi - In The End - Mellen Gi Remix.mp3" but the program only have "In The End - Mellen Gi Remix" these words. How to search for a file in such case.

I tried

```
def findfile(name, path):
for dirpath, dirname, filename in os.walk(path):
    if name in filename:
        return os.path.join(dirpath, name)
filepath = findfile("In The End - Mellen Gi Remix", "C://Users//PycharmProjects")
```

but getting None as result.

Comment: Should you not be doing `return os.path.join(dirpath, filename)`?

Comment: `for fname in filename` ... the argument is a list of files...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `os.walk()` does not return what you're expecting it to. In your example, `filename` is actually a list of file names on each iteration, `dirname` is a list of directory names, and `dirpath` is the path those files and directories are in. Since you're not searching for directories, the middle value can be ignored. In Python, a single underscore `_` is sometimes used as a "throwaway" variable name, that is a variable that must exist because of syntax, but whose value we don't actually care about.

```
def findfile(name, path):
    for dir, _, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for filename in filenames:
            if name in filename:
                return os.path.join(dir, filename)
```

Note that this can still fail to find a file in situations like if the CaSiNg doesn't match, or if áccénts don't match, or if a single character is off, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot its working. but can you please explain why there is need to pass "dir, _, filenames" why it's not working when I enter only filenames in the first for loop ?

Comment: @AshmitSharma There is a need to have three different variables because `os.walk` will give you three different values at a time. So it'll return something like `[(a, b, c), (a, b, c), (a, b, c), ...]`. In this example, `dir = a`, `_ = b`, and `filenames = c`.